# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=A\neq\varnothing$ as set-theoretic limit, is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{diam}(A_n)=\mathrm{diam}(A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space with topology induced by the metric $d$, and $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of sets in $X$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n = A \neq \varnothing$ as a [set-theoretic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit). Is it then true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{diam}(A_n)=\mathrm{diam}(A)$? Knowing the definition of point-wise continuity in the standard topology of metric spaces, I am wondering whether this is a question about the "set-wise" continuity of certain functions in metric spaces. So, is there some known result/counterexample that allows me to conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathrm{diam}(A_n) =\mathrm{diam}(A)$ in general, or is this something you have to (painfully) check everytime in practise?

Comment: $A=\{0\}, A_n=\{0,n\}$. Or $A=\{0\}, A_n=\{0,1-\frac 1 n\}$ if you want bounded sets .

Comment: @geetha290krm Excellent counterexample! Thanks! Do you know what if $A_n$s are assumed to form a decreasing sequence of sets, that is $n\leq m \implies A_m\subset A_n$? Would this alter the situation entirely?

Comment: $A=\{0\}, A_n=\{0,n,n+1,n+2,...\}$.

Comment: $A_n=(0,\frac1n)\cup\{1\}$

Comment: @geetha290krm Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A=\{0\}$ and $A_n=\{0, 1-\frac 1n, 1-\frac 1 {n+1},1-\frac 1 {n+2},\cdots\}$ then $A_n$ **decreases** to $A$, $diam (A)=0$ and $diam (A_n) \to 1$.

Comment: If we consider the case of $A_{n+1} = A_n \cup \{x_{n+1}\}$ ($x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for some finite $d$) such that $A_n$ is increasing to $A$ where $diam(A) < \infty$. Could we say $diam (A_n) \to diam (A)$ in this case?